# CERB - income requirement for small business owners - Can you refile and opt not to claim every expense?

Tags: canada, covid-19

So with the government clarification coming out that CERB qualification is based on $5k net income in 2019 rather than $5k gross income we are in a position where my family did not qualify for CERB.

I have a question based around 3 points:

1. you can refile at any time
2. the language around claiming income is clear in that "must" is used
3. the language around claiming expenses is clear in that "can" is used

If one were to refile using  “we are not legally required to claim those expenses even though they were deductible and it is disadvantageous for us to do so” as a justification, would you be able to qualify?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following Global News article...

https://globalnews.ca/news/7513742/self-employed-cerb-repayments-tax-fix/

Comment: Good article but you should summarize.  Basically, no you don't have to claim all expenses.  Much more info in the article.

Comment: -1. The link doesn’t show the article you referred to. From my phone’s browser, the first article in your link is about Coronavirus and vaccines. It would be much better to type a summary of your findings into your answer.